# Why does using the year 20,000 in MySQL have a different result

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the exact same table when I run the following two queries on MYSQL (version 5.6.37) I get very different results which makes no sense to me...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM salesTransactions WHERE date<'2000-01-01'
```

I get 159 results (as expected). However when I then run the same report but increase the year to 20,000 I get a completely different result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM salesTransactions WHERE date<'20000-01-01'
```

I get the result 6.

How is that possible? If I change the date to 30,000 I get the expected result count. I played around and the year 20100 has 8 results, which is another number.

The table is:

ID: integer
Date: date
Name: varchar(32)

How can this be?

Comment: It would be nice if you created an sql fiddle with sample data where we can reproduce this behaviour. My guess is that your date field is not date, but varchar and therefore mysql uses text comparison as opposed to date comparison. Without data my response is: I could not reproduce your behaviour.

Comment: It is a date field.

Comment: The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Comment: So basically any date after the year 9999 could result in a random result set. That's interesting...

Comment: @P.Salmon - Looks like your S.O.L if you're dates are higher than 9999: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159330/mysqlrepresent-years-greater-than-9999 Just like you said, they expect you to use another data type in those cases.

Comment: @P.Salmon - If you want to create an answer I'll accept it since you found the answer.

Comment: Could you please post the actual date of 8 records?

Comment: @Forward - the exact dates in the table are irrelevant. The issue is that the query is asking for a date with a year larger than 9999, after which point there are no guarantees as to what will happen. Personally I believe if larger dates are not supported it should result in an error but unfortunately it does some processing and comes back with an invalid result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'. The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

Interestingly you would expect the implicit date conversion to return null and so the query would return nothing. So I ran a little test.

```
Select count(*) from awsalesorderheader
union all
select count(*) from awsalesorderheader where orderdate < '9999-01-01' 
union all
select count(*) from awsalesorderheader where orderdate < '20049-01-01' 
union all
select count(*) from awsalesorderheader where orderdate < '20050-01-01' 
union all
select count(*) from awsalesorderheader where orderdate < '20070-01-01' 
union all
select count(*) from awsalesorderheader where orderdate < '10000-01-01' 
union all
select count(*) from awsalesorderheader where orderdate < '40000-01-01' 
union all
select count(*) from awsalesorderheader where orderdate < '30000-01-01' 
union all
select count(*) from awsalesorderheader where orderdate < null 
;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    31466 |
|    31466 |
|        0 |
|     1379 |
|    17514 |
|        0 |
|    31466 |
|    31466 |
|        0 |
+----------+
9 rows in set (0.26 sec)
```

Notice there is a cutoff at 20049-01-01 after which I start to get counts > 0. My mind jumps to the (probably wrong) conclusion that y2k hasn't gone away.